Why can't I run the program when I upgrade Flutter?
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/flutter_slidable-d10a912aae1fb0da330d9c83169f15ed2b0b42a2/lib/src/actions.dart:102:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'primary'.
primary: effectiveForegroundColor,
^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/outlined_button.dart:138:22: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
static ButtonStyle styleFrom({
^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1419

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.



Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I try uninstall & install android studio a new version

Try setting flutter_slidable to the highest version. It looks like the error lies in there. You are probably using an old version of it that isn't compatible with the latest Flutter version.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Right click on android folder and goto open in than exoplorer and close the android studio and than delete your android folder from you project after that reopen android studio goto terminal and command flutter create .
